# i want to change the color of the dynamic div(by using backend am getting 4 divs ) using php

Tags: php

I want this type of appearance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwM93.jpg)

But am getting below result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14TOu.jpg)

I want different color for each div...by using while loop am getting those four divs..Here am writing css properties for one div those are reflecting for four divs

Comment: Post the code as Text not images

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array for the four different colos (CSS classes for the colors), e.g.

```
$colors = array('green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow');
```

Then declare the four classes in CSS, e.g.,

```
.green { background-color: green; /* and other styles etc */ }
.red { background-color: red; /* and other styles etc */ }
.blue { background-color: blue; /* and other styles etc */ }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; /* and other styles etc */ }
```

Then in you PHP script, use some loop counter like `$i` to pick a color from the array:

```
$i=0;
foreach($testimonials as $testimonial)
{
   echo '<div class="' . $colors[$i++] . '">other content</div>';
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 //print_r($row);
  
?>
<style>

</style>
<div class="col-md-6  " style="background-color:<?php echo $row['Message'] ?> !important">
 
<div class=" kwikmint-message">
 <p class="kwikmint-message-p">
 "<?php echo $row['Message'] ?>"
 </p>
 
 </div> 
 <div class="mint-testi-h5">
 <h5><?php echo $row['Name'] ?><br><span class="specialization">
 <?php  echo $row['Specilisation']  ?></span></h5></div>
</div>
 <?php }?>

Comment: this is my html code where should add yhis condition

Answer (score 0):

Set four classes And before while loop set variable $i=1;

Now

```
<?php echo '
<style>
    .div-1{background:#186aa9;}/*blue*/
    .div-2{background:#e1404f;}/*red*/
    .div-3{background:#f8bc34;}/*yellow*/
    .div-4{background:#9cc03c;}/*green*/
</style>';
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){echo '
    <div class="col-md-6 div-'.$i.'">
        <div class=" kwikmint-message">
            <p class="kwikmint-message-p">"'.$row['Message'].'"</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mint-testi-h5">
            <h5>'.$row['Name'].'<br><span class="specialization">'.$row['Specilisation'].'</span></h5>
        </div>
    </div>';
    $i++;
}?>
```

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {

 //print_r($row);
  
?>
<style>

</style>
<div class="col-md-6  div-'.$i.' " style="background-color:<?php echo $row['Message'] ?> !important">
 
<div class=" kwikmint-message">
 <p class="kwikmint-message-p">
 "<?php echo $row['Message'] ?>"
 </p>
 
 </div> 
 <div class="mint-testi-h5">
 <h5><?php echo $row['Name'] ?><br><span class="specialization">
 <?php  echo $row['Specilisation']  ?></span></h5></div>
</div>
 <?php }?>

Comment: this is my while loop condition